# Package existing Titanium Module for Appcelerator Studio

Tags: module, appcelerator, stripe-payments, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to import [this Stripe](https://github.com/RavindraChherke/Stripe-module-for-Appcelerator-Titanium-iOS-and-Android) module into my project but can't seem to figure out how to do it. There is no distribution file to import into the project. I can't seem to find a guide on how to create one. I also read to in the Readme file that I just just drop the distribution files into the library/application support/Titanium folder, but I am using Appcelerator studio. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hello Leonardo, 
              copy and paste dist folder in rootProject/modules/android and rootProject/modules/iphone

- [Dist Android](https://github.com/RavindraChherke/Stripe-module-for-Appcelerator-Titanium-iOS-and-Android/blob/master/stripe_android/android/dist/com.ravindra.stripe.zip) (unzip)
- [Dist iPhone](https://github.com/RavindraChherke/Stripe-module-for-Appcelerator-Titanium-iOS-and-Android/blob/master/stripe_ios/iphone/dist/com.ravindra.stripe.zip)  (unzip)

Appcelerator Documentation:
[How using a module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Using_a_Module)

I check this process and works